# Suppose $E[( \theta-\hat{\theta}_n)^2] = O(n^{-1/2})$. Show that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\theta-\hat{\theta}_n)^2 = O_p(n^{-1/2}).$

Tags: probability, convergence, asymptotics

Assume that $E[( \theta-\hat{\theta}_n)^2] = O(n^{-1/2})$. How can I show that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\theta-\hat{\theta}_n)^2 = O_p(n^{-1/2})?$

What I'm trying to ask is: if the expected value of some quantity is $O(n^{-1/2})$, does that imply the sample mean of that quantity is also $O_p(n^{-1/2})$?

Comment: Are you sure you have the subscript notation right? You’re using the same stuff for random sequences and nonrandom sequences

Comment: @Taylor Could you elaborate? Are you talking about the subscript $n$ for $\hat{\theta}$?

Comment: Sorry if my notation is confusing. What I'm trying to ask is: if the expected value of some quantity is $O_p(n^{-1/2})$, does that imply the sample mean of that quantity is also $O_p(n^{-1/2})$?

Comment: It's not confusing, it's just incorrect. $O_p$ is not the same as $O$ @Adrian

Comment: @Taylor can you point me to a resource that explains the difference between the two notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You want to show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation#Big_O:_stochastic_boundedness) that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exist two positive reals $M$ and $N$ such that
$$\mathbb P\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\theta-\hat{\theta}_n)^2 > M\right)\le\varepsilon\ \ \forall n\ge N $$
Let $\varepsilon>0$. For any $n\ge1$ and $M>0$ you have, by Markov inequality, that
$$\begin{align}\mathbb P\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\theta-\hat{\theta}_n)^2 > M\right)&\le\frac 1 M\mathbb E\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\theta-\hat{\theta}_n)^2 \right]\\
&\le\frac{1}{M\sqrt n}\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (\theta-\hat{\theta}_n)^2 \right]\\
&\le\frac{\sqrt n}{M}\mathbb E\left[(\theta-\hat{\theta}_n)^2 \right]\\\end{align} $$
But, because you assume that $E[( \theta-\hat{\theta}_n)^2] = O(n^{-1/2})$ (it's a deterministic sequence so I assume the big O is the usual one, otherwise it makes no sense), you know that for any positive $M'$, there exists $N'$ such that, for all $n\ge N'$ :
$$\sqrt nE[( \theta-\hat{\theta}_n)^2] \le M' $$
Now take $M'=M\varepsilon$ and you can conclude that the desired inequality holds for all $n\ge N'$.

[Note that I assumed that the $\theta$ in the sum were supposed to be $n$ i.i.d. realizations of $\theta$ called $\theta_i$.]

Comment: Should it be $P\left(\sqrt{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\theta - \hat{\theta}_n)^2 > M\right) \leq \epsilon$ in the first line? Because I want to show that $\sum_{i=1}^n (\theta - \hat{\theta}_n)^2$ is $O(n^{-1/2})$.

Comment: If so, then I have $P\left(\sqrt{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (\theta - \hat{\theta}_n)^2 > M\right) \leq \frac{n}{M} \sqrt{n}E[(\theta - \hat{\theta}_n)^2]$. Since $E[(\theta - \hat{\theta})^2] = O(n^{-1/2})$, then $\sqrt{n}E[(\theta - \hat{\theta}_n)^2] \leq M'$. Therefore, should I take $M' = \frac{M\epsilon}{n}?$ Is it OK for $M'$ to depend on $n$?

Comment: No, you are trying to prove that $$U_n =\color{red}{\frac{1}{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n (\theta-\hat{\theta}_n)^2 $$
Is $O_p(n^{-1/2})$, so when you apply the definition you end up with the expression I've written. Regarding your second question, $M'$ can not depend on $n$ as it is supposed to be a constant (again, look at the definition from Wikipédia).